# How do I swap some characters of a String with values of a HashMap<String,String> in Kotlin?

Tags: list, hashmap, kotlin, higher-order-functions

Assuming I have a

```
val s: String = "14ABC5"
```

and have a `HashMap`

```
val b: HashMap<String,String> = hashMapOf("A" to "10", "B" to "11", "C" to "12", "D" to "13", "E" to "14", "F" to "15" )
```

How would I change all occurrences of A,B,C with 10, 11, 12 while keeping their order ("1", "4", "10", "11", "12", "5")?

So far I have this

```
val result: List<String> = s.toUpperCase().toCharArray().map{ it.toString() }.map{ it -> b.getValue(it)}
```

which works if ALL characters of the `String` exist in the `HashMap` but my `String` may contain **inexistent** keys as well.

Comment: Rather than "swap some elements of a `List<String>`..." it sounds like you're really asking about how to "replace some elements of a `String`...".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Technically yes but since I am converting it into a CharArray and then mapping that into a List<String> I get stuck at manipulating that list. I just wanted to be specific at where my problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use [`getOrDefault(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get-or-default.html), or the Kotlinesque [`b[it] ?: it`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator).

---

<sub>By the way, if you're using the implicit lambda argument name (`it`), you can get rid of the `it ->`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String` as an iterable by default and simplify your code as follows:

```
s.map { it.toString() }
 .map { b[it] ?: it }
```